# Finding unweighted shortest paths between two sets of nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am interested in finding the length of the shortest (unweighted) paths for a set of node pairs efficiently. The answer to the query should be a path length for each node pair. I am wondering whether the [Graph Data Science library](https://neo4j.com/product/graph-data-science/) has a built-in algorithm for this problem.

On an example `(:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(:Person)` graph, searching between two sets of `Person` nodes, the problem can be formulated in vanilla Cypher as follows:

```
:param personPairs: [{person1Id: 123, person2Id: 456}, {person1Id: 789, person2Id: 456}]

UNWIND $personPairs AS personPair
MATCH (person1:Person {id: personPair.person1Id}), (person2:Person {id: personPair.person2Id})
OPTIONAL MATCH path = shortestPath((person1)-[:KNOWS*]-(person2))
RETURN personPair.person1Id, personPair.person2Id, path
```

With the GDS library, I can create a projected graph:

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher('knows',
    'MATCH (p:Person) RETURN id(p) AS id',
    'OPTIONAL MATCH (personA:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(personB:Person)
    RETURN id(personA) AS source, id(personB) AS target'
)
```

Then run [`gds.shortestPath.dijkstra`](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/dijkstra-source-target/) with uniform edge weights:

```
UNWIND $personPairs AS personPair
MATCH (person1:Person {id: personPair.person1Id}), (person2:Person {id: personPair.person2Id})
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream('knows', { sourceNode: id(person1), targetNode: id(person2) })
YIELD totalCost
RETURN toInteger(totalCost) AS length
```

However, this is approx. 50x slower than the vanilla solution. I tried the [`gds.bfs.stream`](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/bfs/) procedure by using `gds.bfs.stream('knows', { sourceNode: id(person1), targetNodes: [id(person2)] })` but this seems incapable of returning the shortest path length.

The GDS library has an [`msbfs` package](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/tree/fb199c8c8dd4e8df4239f737f887204ed83e587a/algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/gds/msbfs) implementing various multi-source BFS algorithms which could be useful for this problem. However, these are not exposed on the API.

Comment: Did the vanilla solution, didn't gave the expected results?

Comment: It yields the expected results but a GDS-based solution, which uses a projected graph (a compact in-memory CSR data structure), could yield better performance with an (MS-)BFS algorithm.